# Half top-down view collision and mechanics

Tags: collision-detection, physics

I'd like to create a game with a half top-down (2d RPG) view (I don't know the exact name of it). It would be 2d, but I'd like to add 3d-like collisions. For example:
[image]

If the grenade lands on the roof, it would roll down and fall. Or if it hits a wall, it would bounce back.

I've never worked with this view, that's why I'm asking for advices for how to do proper collisions and physics. I don't want to use any external libraries.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just for clarity, is the grenade bound by tiles or is it free-moving?

Comment: It is free-moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer will be: Use 3D Colliders

It's possible to freeze one of the axes (z-axis) when the grenade is bouncing back from a 3D Collider, hence it will only moves in x-axis and y-axis.

Apply a sphere collider and rigidbody(with z-axis frozen) on the grenade, a cube collider with thin z-scale on the roof, when the grenade is thrown to the roof, collisions occur and the grenade will be bounced back.

Comment: I have no idea how I'm gonna do that in java (yes, I'm using java).

Comment: May I ask what engine are you using?

Comment: Nothing. I'm writing it from scratch. I'm not even using OpenGL, decided to use CPU rendering and the only GPU drawcall I use is to draw the image.

Comment: In this case, either you write your own 3DPhysics, or instantly transforming the position(without the Physics Logic).
EDIT: To use this, divide the roof into square tiles. When a grenade falls on a certain tile, move the grenade backwards a few tiles from the roof.

Comment: @CodezMe Within the format of a Q&A site, we won't be able to tell you how to build a whole physics engine from scratch. Try reading up on tutorials/books like "Realtime Collision Detection" and ask if you encounter a specific issue or bug you need help sorting out.

Comment: [Image for Tiles Explaination](http://postimg.org/image/oc1ebeb27/)

Comment: @FattyMieo That looks simple but a good solution!

Comment: Glad to hear it :)